# "yolov3_custom First section must be [net] or [network]: No such file or directory darknet: ./src/utils.c:256: error: Assertion `0' failed."

Tags: python, yolo, darknet

YOLOv3 custom data training model having an error when training pre-trained weights on custom data Using Darknet framework with the darknet53.conv.74 pre-trained model and yolov3.cfg that i edited to suit my custom data:
example of what my .txt file for the bounding box looks like: (0 0.336232 0.320863 0.052174 0.515108), i have only 1 class so it's 0.
I have changed the classes number to 1, filters to 18((classes+5)*3), batches 4000(minimum), min/max batches(3800-4200) and of course changed all the 3 [Yolo] layers with their convolutional layers, Height = Width, etc..
I'm working on google.collab but i edit my files on my machine which is windows.
I checked for the CR - LF, using windows and my files contain "\n" so i did not change them assuming it works fine with a windows machine.
i have my test and train files filled, labelled_data.data, "!file" compiled correctly, checked the path `!darknet/darknet detector train custom_data/labelled_data.data darknet/cfg/yolov3_custom.cfg custom_weight/darknet53.conv.74 -dont_show` assuming i took care of all the details and everything will work fine.
BUT,i keep getting this error when i try t o train the model:

```
yolov3_custom
First section must be [net] or [network]: No such file or directory
darknet: ./src/utils.c:256: error: Assertion `0' failed.
```

I don't know what could've gone wrong with this!

Answer (score 1):

if you create your files in windows and try to run in linux machine, you should change your encode using dos2unix library

```
!sudo apt install dos2unix
```

and then :

```
!dos2unix ./data/train.txt
!dos2unix ./data/train.txt
!dos2unix ./data/yolo.data
!dos2unix ./data/yolo.names
!dos2unix ./cfg/yolo-obj.cfg
```

this worked for me

Comment: it was solved, the problem was the parameters in yolov3.cfg file, changed batch_size from 16 to 64 and it worked, but now my model does not save the trained weights in that backup folder, max saved is always 900 batches..